# Processing - loadStrings() case-insensitive

Tags: processing, case-sensitive, case-insensitive

Is there any way to load a text file in Processing while ignoring the case of the file name? I am opening multiple csv files, and some have the extension capitalized, ".CSV" rather than the standard ".csv", which results in errors due to the `loadStrings()` function being case-sensitive.

```
String file = sketchPath("test.csv");
String[] array = loadStrings(file);
```

The above gives the error:

> This file is named test.CSV not test.csv. Rename the file or change your code.

I need a way to make the case of the file name or extension not matter. Any thoughts?

Comment: What are sketchPath and loadStrings? Can you show the code?

Comment: Apologies - this is Processing code (ide built on java). I have removed the java tag.

Comment: I don't think [tag:csv] is at all relevant since the problem you are experiencing does not depend on the filetype, just capitalisation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: No. The case-sensitivity of files comes from the operating system itself.

Longer answer: you could create code that just tries to load from multiple places.

Another approach would be to use Java's `File` class, which has functions for listing various files under a directory, then iterating through them and finding the file that you want. More info is available in [the Java reference](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/File.html), but it might look something like this:

```
String[] array = null;
File dir = new File(sketchPath(""));
for(String file : dir.list()){
   if(file.startsWith(yourFileNameHere)){
      array = loadStrings(file);
      break;
   }
}
```

I haven't tested this code so you might have to play with it a little bit, but that's the basic idea. Of course, you might just want to rename your files ahead of time to avoid this problem.

Comment: Thank you. Understood. I can probably use the File class in a similar way to how you have above to deal with the extension issue. Irregular cases in the file names will be trickier but I'll try and find a way to use 'equalsIgnoreCase' in a string comparison similar to your example. 

I would of course rename the files beforehand, but they are software generated results files, and I am handling the data so it isn't an option.

Comment: @Chris The `equalsIgnoreCase()` function would work pretty well with my generla solution, basically just use it instead of the `startsWith()` function. You could also write a script that renames the files ahead of time. :p

Comment: Yes, true, thanks. I've gone with using the error string, as the directories contain a huge amount of other files that don't need to be read so it would be pretty inefficient to loop over them all. Is it bad practice to use the error to my advantage in that way? The problem with renaming is that the files then need to go on to be used by the original software, and need to be named accordingly - renaming them back would be another layer of faff!

Comment: @Chris I really wouldn't worry about "efficiency" with things like this. Reading the filenames of a directory isn't going to slow your application down in any way that you can notice. And yes it's bad practice to use exceptions for control flow. Google something like "Java exceptions control flow" for a ton of results explaining why.

Comment: Fair enough. Yes, understood - makes sense. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

Why not get the new filename from the error itself? To get the error statement into a `String`, we need to wrap `loadStrings` in a `try` and `catch` statement.

```processing
String[] array;
String file = "heLlo.txt";
try {
  //if all is good then we load the file
  array = loadStrings(file);
}catch(Exception e){
  //otherwise when we get the error, we store it in a String
  String error = e.toString();
```

Then we need to use regular expressions to get the filename from the error statement using `match`. The regex is `/named ([^ +])/` (the filename can be assumed not to have any spaces in it).

```processing
  String[]matches = match(error, "named ([^ ]+)");
```

The capture group with be in element `1` in the array containing the matches. So that would be the "real" filename,

```processing
  String realFile = matches[1];
```

Finally we load the real file and store it in our array.

```processing
  array = loadStrings(realFile);
}
```

Sure, if you want, you can put all of this into a function so that you won't have to use this code again and again every time you load a file. But obviously, it would just be easier if you just renamed or checked your filenames ahead in time.

Comment: Very good idea actually - hadn't thought of using the error, thank you.